# How do I upgrade KDE for 16.04?

Tags: kde, plasma

I have KDE Plasma 5.5 installed on Ubuntu 16.04, which is pretty ancient at 1.5 years old, but just the other day they've released 5.10.  Ubuntu Software store says 5.5 is the latest version (yeah right, tell me another one).

So what can I do to get on the latest KDE? there are plenty of bugs in 5.5 that I would like to escape from.

**EDIT:** Looks like it may be worth upgrading Ubuntu as well.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ? Obviously you would need to upgrade ubuntu or compile from source. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software. A simple google search yields - http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/06/plasma-desktop-5-10-available-for-install-in-kubuntu-17-04/

Comment: If having the very latest KDE is your priority, try KDE Neon: there are four choices listed on their [download page](https://neon.kde.org/download).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/06/plasma-desktop-5-10-available-for-install-in-kubuntu-17-04/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports

sudo apt update && sudo apt install plasma-desktop
```